# Why is 'used to troll' a potentially bad keyword?

Tags: offensive-language

CharcoalHQ caught a post about appealing a network wide ban on Meta.SE yesterday.

> Potentially bad keyword in body

The bad keyword is apparently 'used to troll.' What's toxic or potentially bad about 'used to troll?' Can someone explain why this is a blacklisted keyword?

Also this question was caught by CharcoalHQ just now.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Charcoal's spam detection rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing inherently offensive about the phrase "used to troll". What is being expressed is that a specific keyword (unstated in your question) is commonly used in the activity of *trolling*.

Wikipedia describes [trolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll) as

> In Internet slang, a troll is a person who starts flame wars or intentionally upsets people on the Internet by posting inflammatory and digressive,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_troll) extraneous, or off-topic messages in an online community (such as a newsgroup, forum, chat room, or blog) with the intent of provoking readers into displaying emotional responses[2] and normalizing tangential discussion,[3] either for the troll's amusement or a specific gain.

The word or phrase that got "caught" by the algorithm was one that apparently appeared commonly in messages from trolls and less common in "legitimate" messages.

Merriam-Webster also provides a [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/troll) of trolling:

> 2a : to antagonize (others) online by deliberately posting inflammatory, irrelevant, or offensive comments or other disruptive content

Comment: Why is it commonly used in the activity of trolling?

Comment: @user390881 I don't know. You would have to talk to Charcoal, since they are the ones that issued the message. Ask them what words trigger the filter and how they make the determination to add a word to the list.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: I looked at CharcoalHQ and saw a message *[ SmokeDetector | MS ] Potentially bad keyword in body (1): Much Lower speeds on Laptop Ethernet than on WiFi ✏️ by An Amateur on superuser.com* The linked post contained "The Laptop has a Killer E2400 Ethernet." "Killer" is a trade name but also, literally, a word that would require a moderator to examine the content. ++As a verb, "troll" would likewise require moderator attention to see if it is being used with malign intent.